# Rails + Sidekiq: Sidekiq running in wrong environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 app that I deploy using Capistrano. I recently added Sidekiq. It works fine in my development. I'm hosting both `staging` and `preview` on the same server and it's preview that is not functioning properly. When I trigger the worker on preview it goes to staging and hits the staging database. Am I missing configuration to have 2 sidekiq processes coexist on the same server?

Here's my deploy.rb:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require 'sidekiq/capistrano' #<-- sidekiq

load "lib/deployer/deployer.rb"
set :application, "myapp"
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  ...
set :scm_passphrase, ""
defaults
global_defaults
set :stages, ["staging", "preview"]

task :staging do
  set :rails_env, "staging"
  set :user, "deployer"
  server "myserver.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

  defaults
end

task :preview do
  set :rails_env, "preview"
  set :user, "deployer"
  server "myserver.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

  defaults
end
```

It's inconsistent. In preview I just did an action that triggers the worker, and 4 times it went to staging (I could see in the log as well as the console), and 1 time it hit preview like it was supposed to.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is namespace related.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#wiki-using-sidekiqs-configure-blocks

This is what I use in my initializer.

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url:       'redis://localhost:6379/0',
                   namespace: "sidekiq_#{Rails.application.class.parent_name}_#{Rails.env}".downcase }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url:       'redis://localhost:6379/0',
                   namespace: "sidekiq_#{Rails.application.class.parent_name}_#{Rails.env}".downcase }
end
```

Comment: LOL downvoted for a correct answer derived straight from the docs... classic. FWIW redis doesn't have an "environment" per se just different namespaces so you'd better make sure you're connecting to the right one.

Comment: This works correctly. I tested. Just to also add more info to this answer, Sidekiq will run in RAILS_ENV envoronment variable if it is set, or it will use -e [YOUR_ENV] if its set in the command line. Example : `bundle exec sidekiq -e production`

Answer (score 0):

So it would help to see what the action is as well as the worker and any configuration you've set up for Sidekiq. Since you're using Capistrano, have you set up your configuration for Sidekiq

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment

Also, this is probably a bad solution, but it may at least get you past this roadblock. You can set different redis queues, so you could create a staging queue and a preview queue. For it to actually work, you might have to set the queue you're not going to use frequency of checking to 0.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#wiki-queues

In your worker, try adding

```
sidekiq_options :queue => QUEUE
```

and set `QUEUE = :staging` in your staging's environment and `QUEUE = :preview` in your preview's environment.